# Unknown column in 'on clause' do I have the JOIN wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this query here that I made to pull data for an event from our database of sold tickets... It works great if I remove the lines:

```
**IF (wp_sshow_verifys.verifyID IS NULL,TRUE,FALSE) wp_sshow_verifys**
FROM wp_sshow_sales, wp_sshow_tickets
**INNER JOIN wp_sshow_verifys ON wp_sshow_verifys.saleID=wp_sshow_sales.saleID**
```

The goal here is to pull all the data out of the lower live15 table as it does, and to only pull the data from wp_sshow_sales+wp_sshow_tickets if the wp_sshow_sales.saleID is present in the wp_sshow_verifys.saleID table.

I get this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'wp_sshow_sales.saleID' in 'on clause'

I have tried just about everything I can think of, and looked all over for a answer that didn't confound me, but here I am asking for help. Do I have something wrong with the FROM calling two tables?

```
SELECT 
wp_sshow_sales.saleFirstName as first,
wp_sshow_sales.saleLastName as last,
wp_sshow_sales.saleEMail as email,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPStreet as street,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPCity as city,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPState as state,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPZip as zip,
(CASE WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 1 THEN 'Cerro Gordo' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 2 THEN 'Franklin' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 3 THEN 'Butler' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 4 THEN 'Hardin' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 5 THEN 'Floyd' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 6 THEN 'Mitchell' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 7 THEN 'Hancock' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 8 THEN 'Worth' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 9 THEN 'Wright' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 12 THEN 'Dickinson' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 13 THEN 'Howard' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 14 THEN 'Palo Alto' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 15 THEN 'Calhoun' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 16 THEN 'Woodbury' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 17 THEN 'Emmet' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 18 THEN 'Kossuth' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 19 THEN 'Winnebago' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 22 THEN 'Boone' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 23 THEN 'Buena Vista' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 24 THEN 'OBrien' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 25 THEN 'Osceola' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 26 THEN 'Pocahontas' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 27 THEN 'No County' ELSE 'Error No ID' END) AS 'County',
wp_sshow_tickets.ticketQty as qty,
IF (wp_sshow_verifys.verifyID IS NULL,TRUE,FALSE) wp_sshow_verifys
FROM wp_sshow_sales, wp_sshow_tickets
INNER JOIN wp_sshow_verifys ON wp_sshow_verifys.saleID=wp_sshow_sales.saleID
WHERE wp_sshow_sales.saleID = wp_sshow_tickets.saleID

UNION ALL
SELECT
live_15.firstname as first,
live_15.lastname as last,
live_15.email as email,
live_15.street as street,
live_15.city as city,
live_15.state as state,
live_15.zip as zip,
(CASE WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 1 THEN 'Cerro Gordo' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 2 THEN 'Franklin' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 3 THEN 'Butler' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 4 THEN 'Hardin' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 5 THEN 'Floyd' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 6 THEN 'Mitchell' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 7 THEN 'Hancock' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 8 THEN 'Worth' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 9 THEN 'Wright' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 12 THEN 'Dickinson' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 13 THEN 'Howard' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 14 THEN 'Palo Alto' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 15 THEN 'Calhoun' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 16 THEN 'Woodbury' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 17 THEN 'Emmet' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 18 THEN 'Kossuth' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 19 THEN 'Winnebago' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 22 THEN 'Boone' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 23 THEN 'Buena Vista' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 24 THEN 'OBrien' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 25 THEN 'Osceola' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 26 THEN 'Pocahontas' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 27 THEN 'No County' ELSE 'Error No ID' END) AS 'County',
live_15.qty as qty
FROM live_15
```

After fixing my previous mixup I now get: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

```
SELECT 
wp_sshow_sales.saleFirstName as first,
wp_sshow_sales.saleLastName as last,
wp_sshow_sales.saleEMail as email,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPStreet as street,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPCity as city,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPState as state,
wp_sshow_sales.salePPZip as zip,
(CASE WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 1 THEN 'Cerro Gordo' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 2 THEN 'Franklin' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 3 THEN 'Butler' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 4 THEN 'Hardin' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 5 THEN 'Floyd' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 6 THEN 'Mitchell' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 7 THEN 'Hancock' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 8 THEN 'Worth' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 9 THEN 'Wright' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 12 THEN 'Dickinson' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 13 THEN 'Howard' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 14 THEN 'Palo Alto' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 15 THEN 'Calhoun' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 16 THEN 'Woodbury' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 17 THEN 'Emmet' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 18 THEN 'Kossuth' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 19 THEN 'Winnebago' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 22 THEN 'Boone' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 23 THEN 'Buena Vista' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 24 THEN 'OBrien' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 25 THEN 'Osceola' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 26 THEN 'Pocahontas' WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 27 THEN 'No County' ELSE 'Error No ID' END) AS 'County',
wp_sshow_tickets.ticketQty as qty,
IF (wp_sshow_verifys.verifyID IS NULL,TRUE,FALSE) verify
FROM wp_sshow_sales
INNER JOIN wp_sshow_tickets
  ON wp_sshow_sales.saleID = wp_sshow_tickets.saleID
INNER JOIN wp_sshow_verifys 
  ON wp_sshow_verifys.saleID=wp_sshow_sales.saleID

UNION ALL
SELECT
live_15.firstname as first,
live_15.lastname as last,
live_15.email as email,
live_15.street as street,
live_15.city as city,
live_15.state as state,
live_15.zip as zip,
(CASE WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 1 THEN 'Cerro Gordo' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 2 THEN 'Franklin' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 3 THEN 'Butler' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 4 THEN 'Hardin' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 5 THEN 'Floyd' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 6 THEN 'Mitchell' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 7 THEN 'Hancock' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 8 THEN 'Worth' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 9 THEN 'Wright' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 12 THEN 'Dickinson' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 13 THEN 'Howard' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 14 THEN 'Palo Alto' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 15 THEN 'Calhoun' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 16 THEN 'Woodbury' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 17 THEN 'Emmet' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 18 THEN 'Kossuth' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 19 THEN 'Winnebago' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 22 THEN 'Boone' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 23 THEN 'Buena Vista' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 24 THEN 'OBrien' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 25 THEN 'Osceola' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 26 THEN 'Pocahontas' WHEN live_15.ticketTYPE = 27 THEN 'No County' ELSE 'Error No ID' END) AS 'County',
live_15.qty as qty
FROM live_15
```

Lets count columns:
First select: first, last, email, street, city, state, zip, priceID, qty, verify
Second select: first, last, email, street, city, state, zip, priceID, qty

O my... I have a new column called verify, and it's ugly and I don't want it.

Comment: You are choosing a column alias name as table name in `IF (wp_sshow_verifys.verifyID IS NULL,TRUE,FALSE) wp_sshow_verifys` change `wp_sshow_verifys` to something else.

Comment: Yes, you have a join wrong. You can't mix join notation you use inner join and comma notation (FROM `wp_sshow_sales, wp_sshow_tickets`).  Can't use both.  `FROM wp_sshow_sales, wp_sshow_tickets
INNER JOIN wp_sshow_verifys ON wp_sshow_verifys.saleID=wp_sshow_sales.saleID` the `,` between tables doesn't work with inner join.

Comment: May I interest you to use ENUM for priceID, it will be much more manageable that way. AFAIK, ENUM stores values as number so it wont have any overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix join notation.
Get rid of the where clause and replace the , with inner join and move the where to an on clause

```
SELECT 
    wp_sshow_sales.saleFirstName as first,
    wp_sshow_sales.saleLastName as last,
    wp_sshow_sales.saleEMail as email,
    wp_sshow_sales.salePPStreet as street,
    wp_sshow_sales.salePPCity as city,
    wp_sshow_sales.salePPState as state,
    wp_sshow_sales.salePPZip as zip,
    (CASE WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 1 THEN 'Cerro Gordo' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 2 THEN 'Franklin' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 3 THEN 'Butler' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 4 THEN 'Hardin' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 5 THEN 'Floyd' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 6 THEN 'Mitchell' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 7 THEN 'Hancock' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 8 THEN 'Worth' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 9 THEN 'Wright' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 12 THEN 'Dickinson' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 13 THEN 'Howard' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 14 THEN 'Palo Alto' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 15 THEN 'Calhoun' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 16 THEN 'Woodbury' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 17 THEN 'Emmet' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 18 THEN 'Kossuth' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 19 THEN 'Winnebago' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 22 THEN 'Boone' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 23 THEN 'Buena Vista' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 24 THEN 'OBrien' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 25 THEN 'Osceola' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 26 THEN 'Pocahontas' 
          WHEN wp_sshow_tickets.priceID = 27 THEN 'No County' 
          ELSE 'Error No ID' END) AS 'County',
    wp_sshow_tickets.ticketQty as qty,
    IF (wp_sshow_verifys.verifyID IS NULL,TRUE,FALSE) wp_sshow_verifys2
    FROM wp_sshow_sales
    INNER JOIN wp_sshow_tickets
      ON wp_sshow_sales.saleID = wp_sshow_tickets.saleID
    INNER JOIN wp_sshow_verifys 
      ON wp_sshow_verifys.saleID=wp_sshow_sales.saleID
...
```

Also your last column shares a name with a table, alias it differently as commented by Abhik Chakraborty.

and just a comment, you really don't have a table which translates priceID to the value?  it would be far simpler to have an outer join if that data exists in such a table.  As anytime a new priceID comes in, you have to modify this query... bad design in the long run I would think.

-------------- to address new error encountered---

to support the if statement added to the first query now 10 columns...

you need to add a column to the second query.

at a minimum you could do... so the number of columns match, but maybe you need to do a similar if statement to get results in the second query as well.

```
live_15.qty as qty, Null
FROM live_15
```

Comment: I actually didn't think of making a separate table to translate priceID... that's a really good idea. Thanks!

Comment: That query gets me to this point: 

#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

I'm assuming the UNIONed SELECT is now shorter because we just added the verifys into it... I'll bang my head on the table for a few days trying to figure it out, but if you happen to have a answer before that I wouldn't not use it.

Comment: count the number of columns in each of the select statements being union together.  The # columns, or their data types don't match.  update your question with the new select statements being unioned; might be able to help.  (amend it don't remove the original question it may help someone else!)

Comment: the data types match I am certain of that. the script worked fine to pull data from both tables before adding in the IF & INNER JOIN statements to exclude non verified entries. 

I count the same number of columns, but I'm also prone to stupidity when it comes to sql... obviously. I have amended my previous question with the new select statement

Comment: 10 columns in first query, 9 in second.  What do you want to come back in the 2nd query... Null values? if so just add `, null ` after `live_15.qty as qty`

Comment: Bah, I did't really want to have a extra column in there. It provides no usable data to the person reading the table, and just makes clutter.

Comment: Not a choice when using a union statement.  Columns and data types must match.